# Query to a list of dictionaries (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments, filtering, nested-function

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
friends = [
{'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'male', 'sport': 'Basketball'},
{'name': 'Emily', 'gender': 'female', 'sport': 'volleyball'},
]
```

I need to create functions `query`, `select`, and `field_filter` to work with similar lists. These functions have to provide a possibility to select necessary columns and make filtering by these columns.

Example:

```
result = query(friends, 
select('name', 'gender', 'sport'), 
field_filter('sport', *('Basketball', 'volleyball')), 
field_filter('gender', *('male',)))`

[{'gender': 'male', 'name': 'Sam', 'sport': 'Basketball'}]
```

I need to use predefined code:

```
from typing import Dict, Any, Callable, Iterable
DataType = Iterable[Dict[str, Any]]
ModifierFunc = Callable[[DataType], DataType]
def query(data: DataType, selector: ModifierFunc,
      *filters: ModifierFunc) -> DataType:
"""Query data with column selection and filters
:param data: List of dictionaries with columns and values
:param selector: result of `select` function call
:param filters: Any number of results of `field_filter` function calls
:return: Filtered data"""
pass
def select(*columns: str) -> ModifierFunc:
"""Return function that selects only specific columns from dataset"""
pass
def field_filter(column: str, *values: Any) -> ModifierFunc:
"""Return function that filters specific column to be one of `values`"""
pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question implies that `select` and `field_filter` might want to be classes, I don't think that's necessary here; I'd just make them return regular old tuples:

```
select = field_filter = lambda *args: args
```

and then `query` is just a list and dict comprehension where you iterate over the list of dicts and return the `select`ed fields from the dicts that match the `field_filter`s:

```
def query(data, keys, *filters):
    return [
        {k: d[k] for k in keys}
        for d in data
        if all(d[k] in v for k, *v in filters)
    ]
```

```
friends = [
    {'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'male', 'sport': 'Basketball'},
    {'name': 'Emily', 'gender': 'female', 'sport': 'volleyball'},
]
result = query(
    friends,
    select('name', 'gender', 'sport'),
    field_filter('sport', *('Basketball', 'volleyball')),
    field_filter('gender', *('male',))
)
print(result)  # [{'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'male', 'sport': 'Basketball'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

All I could understand is that the 'select' and 'filter' functions both need an inner function (function in function/closure). And these inner functions need to have the original dataset as a parameter to iterate over.

The working solution would be as follows:

```
def query(data: DataType, selector: ModifierFunc,
      *filters: ModifierFunc) -> DataType:

filtered_data = selector(data)
for filter in filters:
    filtered_data = filter(filtered_data)

return filtered_data

def select(*columns: str) -> ModifierFunc:
    search_fields = columns

def selector(data: DataType) -> DataType:
    selected_list = []
    for i in data:
        selected_dict = {key: value for (key, value) in i.items() if key in search_fields}
        selected_list.append(selected_dict)

    data = selected_list
    return data

return selector


def field_filter(column: str, *values: Any) -> ModifierFunc:
flt_key = column
flt_values = values

def filter(data: DataType) -> DataType:
    filtered_list = []
    for i in data:
        if (flt_key in i.keys() and i[flt_key] in flt_values) or not (flt_key in i.keys()):
            filtered_list.append(i)

    data = filtered_list
    return data

return filter
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer if you want to have multiple filters you would need to add lines in `query`:

```
filtered_data = []
for filter in filters:
    if not filtered_data:
        filtered_data += filter(selected_data)
    else:
        filtered_data = filter(filtered_data)
```

and remove condition in `filter`:

```
if flt_key in i.keys() and i[flt_key] in flt_values:
    filtered_list.append(i)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).